# mvn clean install do not use last .class version

Tags: java, maven, maven-3

It seems Maven keep using use an old version of my code when packaging a war archive.

I build my war using a simple "mvn clean install".

I deleted the /target folder by hand and checked that there were no .class elsewhere in my project ([as described here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3281098/1722236)).

Each time I check the generated archive, **an old version of my code has been packaged inside**. Yet, the same code is properly packaged on my colleague's machine (he uses m2e).

Does anyone have the same problem ?

Here is the most relevant part of the POM:

```
<packaging>war</packaging>
... 
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <!-- <version>2.3.2</version> -->
            <configuration>
                <source>1.6</source>
                <target>1.6</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.4</version>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: Show your full pom file? Do you use Eclipse or calling from command line? Which version of Maven do you use?

Comment: I use Maven 3.0.3 and maven-war-plugin 2.4. I use IntelliJ and the command line - with the same result. Could you tell me which part of my POM you wish to inspect and how it is relevant to my problem ? I'd like to avoid bloating the question.

Comment: Did you override the source directory property or is it a standard Maven tree? (Like src/main/java/...)

Comment: Is this a multi module project?

Comment: Good question. It is a standard Maven tree. It is managed by my IDE (IntelliJ IDEA).

Comment: Yes it depends on a separate module. But the code which is not updated is not in that second module.

Comment: Just as an idea: try deleting any version of both modules (the one you're trying to build and the one it depends on) from your local repository. That's the only place I can think of that the old code may still reside if there are no `.class` files present in the project.

Comment: @blalasaadri: Thanks! Your solution worked. Could you write an answer so I can validate it ?

Comment: Doing install in a sibling module (instead of using things like `mvn -pl ...` instead. Furthermore the point is that the depenendcies of that module must be be solved via the local repository. Furthermore by using an older version of Maven 3.0 where Maven 3.0.3 has bugs it is obvious to me. You should update to at least Maven 3.0.5 last official release or update to Maven 3.1.1 ...

Comment: @khmarbaise could you rephrase your comment ? I don't understand what you wrote.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that the old code is still present somewhere; my guess would be your local repository. Try deleting any entry there that could contain the old code and then building your project again.

Comment: I made a clean install of a sibbling-module which was a dependency of my project (although that module did not contain any of the code changes I wanted to see) and it solved the problem.

Comment: @otonglet It is possible that there is a cross dependency at work here, so module a depends on module b and vice versa. If so, you should remove this cross dependency to prevent future problems like this one.

Comment: Alright. I checked but there is no cross-dependency. I don't know how it happened... Thanks for the hint!

Comment: @otonglet Maven does strange things sometimes... ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Check the `<dependency>` entry in pom.xml for that jar file. Change the `<version>` of that dependency to the latest one.

Comment: Thanks, but the code that is not updated is not coming from a dependency.

Comment: @otonglet, But how are you packaging a jar inside a war without providing dependency?

Comment: I'm not packaging a jar inside a war. Should I ? My POM packaging type is WAR. I'm directly writing code inside this maven-war project.