# Why does Maven use already non-existent classes and dependencies from history in build

Tags: intellij-idea, jboss7.x, maven-3, java-ee-6

I am using maven 3.2.1. for my project.
Maven builds artifacts and puts classes and dependencies into them which do not exist. For example, I used omnifaces as dependency in pom-file. I removed omnifaces from pom-file weeks ago but maven still builds it into the artifact. Another issue is, that maven builds an old and the new structure of the project. I removed a package and put all the classes into another package but maven still builds the old package next to the new one. That causes a ClassCastException at some points.
I'd like to know if anyone knows about that problem. Is there a way to configure maven to use only the current dependecies and project structure to build artifacts?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    4.0.0

```
<parent>
    <groupId>myProject</groupId>
    <artifactId>webApplication</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
</parent>

<artifactId>webApplication-war</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>war</packaging>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>myProject</groupId>
        <artifactId>model-jar</artifactId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>myProject</groupId>
        <artifactId>ordering-ejb</artifactId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
        <version>2.5</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.faces</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.faces-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.enterprise</groupId>
        <artifactId>cdi-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.primefaces</groupId>
        <artifactId>primefaces</artifactId>
        <version>5.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>persistence-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.2</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<name>${project.artifactId}-1.0-SNAPSHOT</name>
<!--<url>http://localhost</url> -->

<!--<build>-->
    <!--<finalName>${project.artifactId}-1.0-SNAPSHOT</finalName>-->
    <!--<pluginManagement>-->
        <!--<plugins>-->
            <!--<plugin>-->
                <!--<groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>-->
                <!--<artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>-->
                <!--<version>2.4</version>-->
                <!--<configuration>-->
                    <!--<packagingExcludes>WEB-INF/lib/model-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar</packagingExcludes>-->
                    <!--<webappDirectory>src/main/webapp</webappDirectory>-->
                    <!--<webXml>src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/web.xml</webXml>-->
                    <!--<outputDirectory>${env.M3_REPO}/ordentity/webApplication/1.0-SNAPSHOT</outputDirectory>-->
                <!--</configuration>-->
            <!--</plugin>-->
        <!--</plugins>-->
    <!--</pluginManagement>-->
    <!--<plugins>-->
        <!--<plugin>-->
            <!--<groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>-->
            <!--<artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>-->
            <!--<version>2.8</version>-->
            <!--<executions>-->
                <!--<execution>-->
                    <!--<phase>install</phase>-->
                    <!--<goals>-->
                        <!--<goal>copy</goal>-->
                    <!--</goals>-->
                    <!--<configuration>-->
                        <!--<overWriteIfNewer>true</overWriteIfNewer>-->
                        <!--<artifactItems>-->
                            <!--<artifactItem>-->
                                <!--<groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>-->
                                <!--<artifactId>${project.artifactId}</artifactId>-->
                                <!--<version>${project.version}</version>-->
                                <!--<type>${project.packaging}</type>-->
                            <!--</artifactItem>-->
                        <!--</artifactItems>-->
                        <!--<outputDirectory>${env.JBOSS_HOME}/standalone/deployments</outputDirectory>-->
                    <!--</configuration>-->
                <!--</execution>-->
            <!--</executions>-->
        <!--</plugin>-->
    <!--</plugins>-->
<!--</build>-->
```

Maven puts classes and directories into that war file which do not exist in project structure. I had a package called bean, but deleted it weeks ago. It still appears in the war file. I am really disapointed...

SOLVED: I found a helpful thread (link below) where a comment gave me the solution.
I found a classes directory in my project under:

```
webApplication/war/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF
```

It contained all the old classes which were build into the artifact as well. Therefore maven also built all the dependencies into the artifact. After I deleted the classes directory all the ugly sideeffects disappeared.

[Why might Maven ignore updated classes during install?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3281098/why-might-maven-ignore-updated-classes-during-install)

Comment: Try to run "mvn clean", it might have leftovers in the target/ directory. Did you try to run it outside the IDE to see if the IDE is at fault (at least for Eclipse the auto builders tend to mess things up).

Comment: ty for reply. I tried clean install as well from IDE and command line. The target directory ok, There are all the new classes. But in the artifact it is messed up.

Comment: sounds like you drag in somwehre an old version of your project.

Comment: Well, but from where?

Comment: Please show your full pom file. Furthermore it could be that you have a dependency via a transitive dependency?